# Convert GMP integer to a sum of power of two (2n)

Tags: php, algorithm, gmp

I'm using GMP library of php to solve a problem of formulary.

```
public function gmp_sum($aRessource)
{
    // Avec le while
    $i = 0;
    $nb_ressource = count($aRessource);
    while ($i < $nb_ressource)
    {   
        if ($i == 0)
        {
            $tmp = gmp_init($aRessource[$i]);
        }
        else
        {
            $tmp = gmp_add(gmp_init($aRessource[$i]),$tmp);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

The variable $aRessource is equal to : array(1,2,4,8);

so my function gmp_sum is returning 15.

I want to create an algorithm who does the reverse operation, the function take the integer 15 and return me an array who contains 1 2 4 8. But I do not know where to start.

Thanks for the help

Solution :

Decompose integer to power of 2 in php

```
    public function gmp_reverse($gmp_sum)
{
    $res = array();
    $i = 1;
    while ($i < 64) // 64 bytes
    {   
        $tmp = $gmp_sum & $i; // check if bytes equal to 1
        if ($tmp != 0)
        {
            array_push($res,$i);
        }
        $i = $i * 2;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: How you want to divide 15 to 1 2 4 8 ?? can u explain the output

Comment: @rahulpatel Honestly I don't know exactly myself, but it's the reverse of my function

Comment: I've edited wih the solution to decompose integer to power of 2 sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want an array which adds up to the sum, you want a reverse of that. This function assumes, you have a perfect input, so for example, 17 will not work.
Try it out.

```
function reversegen($gmpsum)
{
    $stack = array();
    $limit = $gmpsum;
    $cur = 1;
    for($sum = 0; $sum < $limit; )
    {
        echo $cur. "<br>";
        array_push($stack,$cur);
        $sum = $sum + $cur;
        $cur = 2 * $cur;
    }
    return($stack);
}


$stack = reversegen(15);
print_r($stack);
```

15 above is for representative purpose. You can use, 31, 63, 127 etc and it will still work fine.

Comment: Bro the code will not work for any number greater than 15

Comment: Yes it's a problem especially for big number gmp thank you for the answer anyway

Comment: and its returning me an empty array btw :/

Comment: Nassim - Can you provide me, the number, you're using. I tried with 31. It seemed to work.
1
2
4
8
16
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 8 [4] => 16 )

Rahul - You need to replace 15 by 31, 63, 127 and so on to see, if it will work or, not.

Comment: @UmashankarDas I tried with 15 for begining and its returning me an empty array()

Comment: Good to hear Nassim. Just try for another number and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you men it works for 1023 thats exactly what i needed :D

Comment: Last question @UmashankarDas can you explain me your loop please ?

Comment: Basically, we check the sum and see if it is > your value and since, you want an addition, we keep adding indexes from 1 ... n.

Happy to help. Feel free to upvote the answer.

Comment: I've updated a bit my function it works faster and for number like 22 for example